# Running elastic mapreduce streaming on AMI 3.0.1

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, hadoop-streaming, amazon-emr

Trying to run a streaming job with the newer AMI 3.0.1: 
I get errors like:

```
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "s3://elasticmapreduce/samples/wordcount/wordSplitter.py": error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:219)
... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:135)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1022)
... 24 more
```

For a very basic example job:

```
elastic-mapreduce --create --ami-version 3.0.1 --instance-type m1.large \
--log-uri s3n://mybucket/logs --stream \
--mapper s3://elasticmapreduce/samples/wordcount/wordSplitter.py \
--input s3://mybucket/input/alice.txt \
```

--output s3://mybucket/output --reducer aggregate

while running the same job on AMI 2.4.2 works fine:

```
elastic-mapreduce --create --instance-type m1.large \
--log-uri s3n://mybucket/logs --stream \
--mapper s3://elasticmapreduce/samples/wordcount/wordSplitter.py \
--input s3://mybucket/input/alice.txt \
--output s3://mybucket/output --reducer aggregate
```

I need to use AMI 3.0.1 because other custom JAR steps use Hadoop 2.2.0.

Comment: In case anyone else has this issue, I've asked on the AWS forums and they are looking into it, and suggest a workaround: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=140004&tstart=0#

Answer (score 0):

While not exactly an answer to this specific question, this question led me to determine an answer when I experienced the same issue when initiating a job directly on the EMR Master.

The solution to the issue I experienced (with Hadoop 2.x provided by the AMI v3.x.x) required the use of the -files option:

```
hadoop jar contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming.jar \
    -files s3n://<my bucket>/mapper.py,s3n://<my bucket>/reducer.py \
    -input s3n://<my bucket>/location/* \
    -output s3n://<my bucket>/emr-output \
    -mapper mapper.py  \
    -reducer reducer.py
```

In the previous version of Hadoop (Hadoop 1.x provided by the AMI v2.4.x) the following statement worked properly:

```
hadoop jar contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming.jar \
    -input s3n://<my bucket>/location/* \
    -output s3n://<my bucket>/emr-output \
    -mapper s3n://<my bucket>/mapper.py  \
    -reducer s3n://<my bucket>/reducer.py
```